# Sprite Kit pause/resume scene isn't working after restart

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a game where I've successfully implemented a pause feature when the home button is pressed. In my View Controller that has the main scene, I pause using:

```
- (void)appWillEnterBackground{
SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.paused = YES;
bubbleOn=NO; //turns bubble spawn off

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(appWillEnterForeground)
 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
 object:NULL];
 }
```

To unpause,

```
- (void)appWillEnterForeground{
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.paused=NO;
bubbleOn=YES; Allows recursive method to run until bubbleOn = YES
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:slowMo target:scene selector:@selector(spawnNew) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; //Recursive spawn method

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(appWillEnterBackground)
 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
 object:NULL];}
```

This works well until my the game ends and a new scene (End Scene) is presented. After the End Scene shows a score, the user can tap again to start again and main scene is presented. The main scene's **initWithSize** method begins the recursive method **spawnNew**. If the app goes to the background, the scene pauses and spawnNew stops.

But when the app goes to foreground, the scene does resume, but the **spawnNew** method does not work. It gets called and outputs a correct NSLog message, but the the method doesn't spawn bubble nodes.

The spawnNew method is in my main scene's implementation:

```
-(void) spawnNew{
if (bubbleOn==YES){
    bubble = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:ballName];
    bubble.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:bubble.size.width/2];
    ...
    //bubble properties
    ...
    [self addChild:bubble];
    NSLog(@"Spawn!");

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:slowMo target:self selector:@selector(spawnNew) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    return;
} else{
    return;
}
```

I'm out of ideas at this point! Any suggestions?

Comment: don't use nstimer, timer won't pause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to get rid of `NSTimer`. You can use `SKAction` instead.

In `SKScene`'s `initWithSize` method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        ....

        __weak GameScene *weakSelf = self;
        SKAction *spawnBubble = [SKAction runBlock:^{
            [weakSelf spawnNew];
        }];
        SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:slowMo];
        [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:
            [SKAction sequence:@[spawnBubble,wait]]]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In this case you don't even need to use `bubbleOn` variable, as scene stops executing any actions as soon as it's `SKView` is paused.

Comment: could you explain why you used __weak?

Comment: to prevent the block from retaining self, not sure if it's necessary here though but it can't hurt

Comment: @akashg @LearnCocos2D I've spent all day yesterday finding out why my scene isn't being freed :) The reason was a retain cycle in `SKAction` block, so I always will use that modificator.

Comment: I was using SKActions before, but the slowMo variable changes with increasing score. The variable itself changes as expected, but the SKAction keeps the original waitForDuration instead of updating to the new slowMo value. Do I need to update the SKAction somewhere before each frame is rendered?

Comment: You can remove that action and add it again with updated slowMo value

Comment: Ah, because actions are immutable!